# TypeError: 'in <string> while send cmd via python telnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

I tried to send `ls /` cmd via python telnet

```
import telnetlib
tel = telnetlib.Telnet('10.10.0.1'.'1234')
tel.write('ls / ')
```

But I got an error :

```
if IAC in buffer:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your string to ASCII:

```
tel.write(('ls / ').encode('ascii'))
```

In Python3, `str` class stores strings as unicode, you need to explicitly convert them to `ascii`. You basically need a byte-string with every character as an ASCII character rahter than a Unicode one.

Comment: See the edit, the strings are passed as unicode, you will need to provide an explicit encoding to ascii to pass in telnetlib. @MicrosoctCprog